# Response is null when I used Restsharp library's GET request to access Json data

Tags: c#, android, json, restsharp

I am using Restsharp library to do Webservice operations.I tried to access data from the link(http://www.mocky.io/v2/595616d92900003d02cd7191) and print it in Console but I am not getting any response.When I used breakpoints,Response is showing null.Here's my code to get data from the link.

```
private async void GetItemsFromJSON()
    {
        IRestClient client = new RestClient("http://www.mocky.io/v2/595616d92900003d02cd7191");
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                IRestResponse<List<ItemDetails>> response = client.Execute<List<ItemDetails>>(request);
                var Items = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<ItemDetails>(response.Content);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

}

```
  public class ItemDetails
{
    public List<Itemschema> items { get; set; }
}
 public class Itemschema
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int attribute_set_id { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public string type_id { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something here?My schema class which corresponds to the Json data is shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that:

```
IRestResponse<List<ItemDetails>> response = client.Execute<List<ItemDetails>>(request);
```

should be:

```
IRestResponse<ItemDetails> response = client.Execute<ItemDetails>(request);
```

http://www.mocky.io/v2/595616d92900003d02cd7191 seems to return an `items` property which contains an array of schemas. That maps closer to `ItemDetails` than `List<ItemDetails>`.

This complete sample works, so you may want to compare it with your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using RestSharp;

namespace Test
{
    public class ItemDetails
    {
        public List<Itemschema> items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Itemschema
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int attribute_set_id { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public int visibility { get; set; }
        public string type_id { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public int weight { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IRestClient client = new RestClient("http://www.mocky.io/v2/595616d92900003d02cd7191");
            IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            IRestResponse<ItemDetails> response = client.Execute<ItemDetails>(request);
            var Items = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<ItemDetails>(response.Content);
            Console.WriteLine(Items.items.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested. Still my response is null. Can you please look into that?

Comment: I have posted a complete sample - how does it differ from your code?

Comment: Thank you so much. I found out that the problem was with my phone's internet not in the code. Eventually it got solved.